# Prove $(\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$ is injective for $0\leq t \lt 1$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove $(\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$ is injective for $0\leq t \lt 1$

Intuitively it makes sense - this traces out the unit circle - but how we do we show this from the definitions / rigourously?

Comment: I think we can also think like this:When $0\leq t <1$ then $0\leq 2\pi t<2\pi$. And $2\pi$ is the period of $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions.

Comment: It will depend on how you define $\cos x$ and $\sin x$. As series or otherwise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(\cos2\pi t,\sin2\pi t)=(\cos2\pi s,\sin2\pi s)$, then we have $2\pi t=2\pi s+3\pi/2\implies t=s+3/4$, and also $2\pi t=2\pi s+\pi/2\implies t=s+1/4$.  Then $s+3/4=s+1/4\implies 1/4=3/4 \Rightarrow \Leftarrow$.

Comment: I was wondering how you got the implication that $2\pi t = 2 \pi s + 3\pi /2$.  I was able to show this using the identity $\cos(t) - \cos(s) = -2 \sin(\frac{t+s}{2}) \sin(\frac{t-s}{2}) = 0$ and the fact that $s, t \in [0, 2\pi)$ but I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: umm, it's well-known that $\cos$ repeats its values, but in the opposite order, so to speak, when we add  $3\pi/2$ (or subtract $\pi/2$).